# Getting the post parameters from an extjs grid

Tags: csv, parameters, grid, store, extjs3

I have an extJs Grid with filters etc. I get my data via ajax from the server.
Everything works fine. I also want to allow the user to download the grid data as csv.

So I wrote a function on serverside (php) which takes the same parameters the gridstore sends and replies with a csv with the right headers.

My problem is that I need the grid parameters to get the right results. I can't find them neither in the grid.store nor in the grid itself.

Any ideas how I can get the "post"-paramters the extjs grid uses in its ajax request?

Comment: what are the parameters you are referring to? is it the paging status? also note that the grid store is the one responsible for executing ajax requests to your PHP handler and not the grid itself. the grid just listens to any store change events and reflect the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution, but stackoverflow didn't let me post it on that day, so i forgot to post it and never looked for answers, sorry.

What I did was:Bind a function on the load event of the grid and save the actual params in a global variable called lastParameters. There it is.

```
grid.store.on('load', function(store, records, options){
  lastParameters = options.params;
});
```